# creating BPEL process with Jdeveloper

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, bpel

I need to create BPEL process on Jdeveloper
please verify following list of softwares i have used

Required Software

RCU

WLS

SOA
soa_generic_11.1.1.2.0_disk1_1of1.zip

JDeveloper
JDev11g.zip

I got this list from anonymous source, so can any one guide me which setup will work for which role and please refer me for any manual through which we can setup the environment.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You can download the components from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/downloads/fmw-11-download-092893.html and you can find the requirements at http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E18558_01/fusion_requirements.htm

Your list is almost complete, only the database is missing. Oracle fusion middleware has an awful lot of components, but what you'll need for BPEL is:

- JDeveloper - it is actually enough to write the processes. If you also want to deploy and run them you also need:
- Oracle Database 11g - to host the BPEL dehydration store and config data
- RCU - to create the database schema for BPEL
- Weblogic Server 10.3.3 - JEE container for SOA suite
- SOA Suite 11.1.1.2.0 - includes BPEL. I dont know any 'BPEL-only' packages
- SOA Suite 11.1.1.3.0 - if you want the latest version

BTW don't even try to install these if you've less than 4GB RAM...

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to teach yourself BPEL you can download the whole suite as a VM from OTN. [Find it here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/learnmore/vmsoa-172279.html) It takes up 30GB of disk space.  The docs say you need 3GB but from experience I know that performance is sluggish on a laptop with 4GB (which on 32-bit Windows is actually 3.5GB).  Basically the more memory the better.    You'll also need [Virtual Box](http://tp://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html).

Obviously for production you'll need to install the components on different servers so this VM is not appropriate.  If you want to use BPEL for production you'll need to get licenses for WLS, BAM and various other bits.  Even by Oracle's standards, the [licensing for SOA products](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/doc.1111/e14860/products.htm#CIBEIJGC) is labyrithine.

Answer (score 2):

Quick reference of the installation of soa 11g ps3.
http://soafarm.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/install-soa-suite-11g-in-windows-xp-os/